# Request with token from ADAL for Cordova returns 401 response from Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm hoping someone can help with this:

I have a web api secured with Azure AD Bearer Authentication, where I have two web clients that can successfully authenticate on the web api using bearer tokens from AD. The Web API and both web applications are configured as applications in AD. I've tried to use ADAL for Cordova for accessing the web api a iOS/Android app but it's returning 401.

`ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is returning false.

I'm using the client id for the native application I've setup in Azure AD, and I'm receiving the token but this token is invalid. After I've parsed the token on jwt.io, everything seems correct but I've noticed the token doesn't have a header.
I've added permissions to access the Web Api and sign in and access AD as the user.
The code I'm using in Cordova is below, the authority I'm using is the same as the other apps that are working. Where resource is the app Id for the Web Api in AD, and client id is the client id for the native app in Azure Ad.

`// Attempt to authorize user silently
        AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId)
        .then(function (result) {
            sessionService.logIn(result.idToken);
            console.log(result);
            deferred.resolve();
        }, function () {
            // We require user credentials so triggers authentication dialog
            AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, redirectUri)
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                sessionService.logIn(result.idToken);
                deferred.resolve();
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("Failed to authenticate" + err);
                deferred.reject("failed to authenticate");
            });
        });`

I've also tried using result.accessCode, which also doesn't work.
StartUp.Auth.cs in Web Api:-

`app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                         ValidAudiences = Audiences
                    }
                });
        }`

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be sending the wrong token to the API - you are supposed to send result.accessToken. See https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-cordova-multitarget/blob/master/DirSearchClient/js/index.js for an example.